# Check in inputs are empty then continue submition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form and I am trying to check if both text fields are empty.
If there are empty then do an alert else continue submition but my code is not working..
Any suggestions?

Unfortunately i have to work with this method and not with ajax.

```
<style>
.highlight{
backgound-color: #F00;  
}
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#register-form").submit(function(){
    var isFormValid = true;

    $(".required input").each(function(){
        if ($.trim($(this).val()).length == 0){
            $(this).addClass("highlight");
            isFormValid = false;
        }
        else{
            $(this).removeClass("highlight");
        }
    });

    if (!isFormValid) alert("Please fill in all the required fields (indicated by *)");

    return isFormValid;
});
});
</script>
```

And inside the body:

```
<form id="register-form" name="register-form" method="post" action="register.php">
  <p>
    <label for="usenrame"></label>
    <input type="text" name="usenrame" id="usenrame" class="required input" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="passwor"></label>
    <input type="text" name="passwor" id="passwor" class="required input" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Class names are space separated so `required input` is defining two classes on the input which invalidates the jQuery selector. You can change the class name(s) to `required-input` or do as Shail said and use the `input.required` jQuery selector.

Comment: Indeed... but it continues the submition after

Comment: Please use a Minimal Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made error in the selector.

Either it need to be :

```
$(".required.input").each(function(){
```

as it's at the same level

else it need to be

```
$("input.required").each(function(){
```

as per your code, you are looking for the children tags `input` inside `.required` class

I would suggest using `.required` alone if you are planning to use `select` box or `textarea` in the future. Same selector can be used for all the cases.

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/xumoy/1/edit)

Answer (score 4):

Here in this line

```
$(".required input").each(function(){
```

You have made mistake

```
$("input.required").each(function(){
```

use this...

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
$("#register-form .required").each(function(){
```

instead of

```
$(".required input").each(function(){
```

This will make sure no other inputs in other `<forms>` are encroached upon by your jQuery selector.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector appears to be wrong. Currently, your selector is selecting the `<input />` element inside of an element that has a class of `.required`. That does not match your markup.

You can either target an `<input />` element with the class of `.required` like the following:

```
$('input.required')...
```

or alternatively target an `<input />` element with both an `.input` and a `.required` class like the following:

```
$('.required.input')...
```